# After move TFS, Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo returns old host name

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017

We recently moved our TFS-Instance to another server. I've changed the TFS mapping in the Visual Studio Settings for 'Manage connections' - Get latest version and all TFS features work as expected.

**Problem:** We have a tool, which allows us to move files to a dedicated directory in TFS by it's filename. To determine the TFS uri, this tool uses the following code:

```
WorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(sourceDirectory);
```

and this method returns the old TFS uri instead of the new one, even though the workspace information mapping points to our new server...?

[image: Workspace information is correct]
[image: And debug output returns still old host path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a command prompt as administrator and change the directory to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE or the corresponding directory depending on your Visual Studio version.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
```

Then run the following command:

```
tf workspaces /collection:http://ServerName:Port/VirtualDirectoryName/CollectionName
```

in my case this was:

```
tf workspaces /collection:http://tfs.domain.com/DefaultCollection
```

This will refresh the version control cache and

```
Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(sourceDirectory);
```

should return your new TFS URI.